# Better way to require jQuery in CommonJS modules?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mocha.js, browserify

I'm just starting-out with Node.js, Mocha and Browserify.

I have a module that depends upon jQuery, and my spec for it also depends upon jQuery. In order to simply do `require('jquery')` in the module, as opposed to `require('jquery')(window)`, I've created a jsdom `window` in my spec file and assigned it to `global.window`:

```js
var $;

beforeEach(function () {
    var doc = jsdom.jsdom('<html><body></body></html>');

    global.window = doc.createWindow();

    $ = require('jquery');

    ...
});
```

In this way my specs can use jQuery to find DOM nodes and test expectations, and my module can use jQuery without having to explicitly be passed a `window`.

This all seems to work OK, but is it the "right" thing to do? I've searched a lot and can't find any other mention of using `global.window` this way to pass to jQuery. Technically I suppose `window` is a dependency for my module, so should I explicitly pass it to my module and live with calling `require('jquery')(window)` instead of `require('jquery')`?

What is the common practice for creating CommonJS modules that require jQuery?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having run into more problems with multiple DOMs (created using jsdom) for different examples I realised my error. Instead of requiring jQuery in my specs and in my modules I should **only** require it in my specs, and pass it into my modules as a dependency; i.e. the modules shouldn't `require('jquery')` at all.

Once I realised this it seemed self-evident, which is probably why I've struggled to find any relevant documentation online.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to avoid is making `window` a global, you can pass your `window` object to the `jquery` module, like this:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var $;

beforeEach(function () {
    var doc = jsdom.jsdom('<html><body></body></html>');

    var window = doc.createWindow();

    $ = require('jquery')(window);
});

it("foo", function() {
    console.log($("body"));
});
```

Comment: Yep, I realise I can do that inside ```beforeEach()```, but I don't want to do that inside my module because.

Comment: You did not finish your sentence there. Because what?

Comment: Sorry, I was interrupted and then didn't come back. I don't want to have to explicitly pass the window into my module as a dependency. Although now I think about it, perhaps I should do that...